# Updating to Entity Framework 6 invalid "LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProviderAttribute"

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, objectcontext, entity-framework-6

I update to EF6 using NuGet packages, change all the namespaces and fix the rest of the build errors and I get this:

> Type 'DatumBase.DomainServices.ProjectEntities' is not a valid LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProviderAttribute parameter because it does not derive from ObjectContext.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets

When clearly:

> public partial class ProjectEntities: ObjectContext

it does.

I'm assuming this is related to the namespace changes from EF 5 to 6. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: If they expect the `ObjectContext` from EF5 you cannot use the one from EF6. EF5 and EF6 are not binary compatible. Think about it this way - if you created your own class accidently called `ObjectContext` and derive your `ProjectEntities` class from it would it work? Obviously it would not. You need to think about EF6 `ObjectContext` the same way - even though it is an evolution of the `ObjectContext` from EF5 from the app perspective it is a totally different type. So if the framework you are using does not support EF6 you won't be able to use EF6.